# Pandas: Transform column to join unique elements

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am doing a groupby in Pandas to combine data however I want to only include the unique elements in the column.

I am currently running:

```
df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])['Grade'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

which will produce:

```
Col1   Col2   Grade
1      1      A-,A-,B+
1      2      A,B,B-,B-
2      1      B,C,C,D
...
```

How do I perform a join only on the unique elements of the grade column so my output looks like:

```
Col1   Col2   Grade
1      1      A-,B+
1      2      A,B,B-
2      1      B,C,D
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set` to drop duplicates in your aggregation:

```
df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])['Grade'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(set(x)))
```

Or to keep the correct order, use `np.unique`:

```
df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])['Grade'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(np.unique(x)))
```