# Python Lambda Join Function to Return Semi Colon List of Unique Values Giving Attribute Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF that looks like this.

[image]

My desired output is a DF that looks like this:

[image]

Here's the code I've tried:

```
test = df.groupby('Group', as_index=True).agg(lambda x: '; '.join(el for el in x if el !=''))
```

But this gives me the below.

[image]

When I use [(per this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62076267/pandas-transform-column-to-join-unique-elements):

```
test = out.groupby('DocSetID', as_index=True).agg(lambda x: '; '.join(el for el in x if el !='').set(x))
```

I get an error reading:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can the code be fixed to only include one of each value?

Comment: You are not running the code from the linked post, double check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there, you have to apply `set` to the list of values to join:

```
test = out.groupby('DocSetID', as_index=True).agg(lambda x: '; '.join(set(el for el in x if el !='')))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the set incorrectly, also take advantage of the set difference:

```
test = out.groupby('DocSetID', as_index=True).agg(lambda x: '; '.join(set(x).difference([''])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm sure there is a more elegant way to solve this problem, here is a slight change to your code based on the other answer you supplied. You used `.set()` as a method of your output string. Instead you can apply it as a function to the list within the `.join()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"Group": [1, 1], "Val1": ["A", "A"], "Val2": ["B", ""], "Val3": ["C", "D"]})
df.groupby("Group").agg(lambda x: '; '.join(sorted(set(el for el in x if el !=''))))
```

Note that this does not handle nulls -- only empty strings, you'd have to add that condition in the if statement.